# What is the Big Oh Efficiency of Program with Finite For Loop?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

What would be the efficieny of the following program, it is a for loop which runs for a finite no. of times.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
   //do something here, no more loops though.
}
```

So, what should be the efficiecy. O(1) or O(n) ?

Comment: The answer depends on what is the complexity of the loop body.

Comment: `O(1)` if `10` is constant that is not related to `n`, otherwise `O(n)`

Comment: O(1), since there is no N in the algorithm.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) { i = 0; }` It's a Big Oh No!

Comment: Note that `O()` is usually not used in terribly formal manner. For example - computers have finite memory - finite number of states, so every computation that terminates, terminates in `O(1)`. Or, loop `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++ )` does at most `INT_MAX = O(1)` steps.

Comment: @zch: It's for describing the properties of an algorithm, not any concrete implementation of that algorithm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That entirely depends on what is in the `for` loop. Also, computational complexity is normally measured **in terms of the size `n` of the input**, and I can't see anything in your example that models or represents or encodes directly or indirectly the size of the input. There is just the constant `10`.

Besides, although sometimes the analysis of computational complexity may give unexpected, surprising results, the correct term is *not* "**[Big Oh](http://www.seo-chicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/2000px-Face-surprise.jpg)**", but rather **[Big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)**.

Answer (score 4):

You can only talk about the complexity with respect to some specific input to the calculation.  If you are looping ten times because there are ten "somethings" that you need to do work for, then your complexity is O(N) with respect to those somethings.  If you just need to loop 10 times regardless of the number of somethings - and the processing time *inside* the loop doesn't change with the number of somethings - then your complexity with respect to them is O(1).  If there's no "something" for which the order is greater than 1, then it's fair to describe the loop as O(1).

---

*bit of further rambling discussion...*

O(N) indicates the time taken for the work to complete can be reasonably approximated by some constant amount of time plus some function of N - the number of somethings in the input - for huge values of N:

- O(N) indicates the time is c + xN, where c is a fixed overhead and x is the per-something processing time,
- O(log<sub>2</sub>N) indicates time is c + x(log<sub>2</sub>N),
- O(N<sup>2</sup>) indicates time is c + x(N<sup>2</sup>),
- O(N!) indicates time is c + x(N!)
- O(N<sup>N</sup>) indicates time is c + x(N<sup>N</sup>)
- etc..

Again, in your example there's no mention of the number of inputs, and the loop iterations is fixed.  I can see how it's tempting to say it's O(1) *even if* there are 10 input "somethings", but consider: if you have a function capable of processing an arbitrary number of inputs, then decide you'll only use it in your application with exactly 10 inputs and hard-code that, you clearly haven't changed the performance characteristics of the function - you've just locked in a single point on the time-for-N-input curve - and any big-O complexity that was valid before the hardcoding must still be valid afterwards.  It's less meaningful and useful though as N of 10 is a small amount and unless you've got an horrific big-O complexity like O(N<sup>N</sup>) the constants c and x take on a lot more importance in describing the overall performance than they would for huge values of N (where changes in the big-O notation generally have much more impact on performance than changing c or even x - which is of course the whole point of having big-O analysis).

Answer (score 2):

Sure O(1), because here nothing does not depend linearly of n.

**EDIT:**
Let the loop body to contain some complex action with complexity O(P(n)) in Big O terms.

If we have a constant C number of iterations, the complexity of loop will be O(C * P(n)) = O(P(n)).

Else, now let the number of iterations to be Q(n), depends of n. It makes the complexity of loop O(Q(n) * P(n)).

I'm just trying to say that when the number of iterations is constant, it does not change the complexity of the whole loop.

Comment: I disagree, it can be for example `O(n)`, depending on what is inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. Good addition. But I really think that the asker had in mind some simple, constant-time action in the loop.
Now I think I can clarify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`n` in [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) denotes the input size. We can't tell what is the complexity, because we don't know what is happening inside the `for` loop. For example, maybe there are recursive calls, depending on the input size? In this example overall is `O(n)`:

```
void f(int n) // input size = n
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        //do something here, no more loops though.
        g(n); // O(n)
    }
}

void g(int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        g(n - 1);
    }
}
```